# JQuery auto-complete input event

Tags: jquery, html

On my search webpage I have a simple JQuery script which enables a submit button if there is text in the input box.

I am using the `keyup` event in order to detect typing, however I am not sure how to handle events where a user may click the input field and scroll down to a previously searched query.

No key event is able to detect this action, what can I do?

**JQuery code**

```
/* if search box has text then enable submit button otherwise disable it */
$(".searchContainer input[name=query]").keyup(function(){
    if($(".searchContainer input[name=query]").val().length > 0){
        $(".searchContainer input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else{
        $(".searchContainer input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

**HTML markup**

```
<form method="post" action="/results.php">
   <input type="text" name="query" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

**Edit**

[image]

I basically want to handle auto-complete events, im not interested in disabling the feature,  I want to know how to detect if an auto-complete option has been selected.

Comment: what do you mean by "user may click the input field and scroll down to a previously searched query"?

Comment: You may have to handle the events provided by the autocomplete feature

Comment: as I understood correctly, you can also use `onchange` event, but the best solution would the turning off browser built-in autocomplete

Comment: yes, as I thought that was built-in autocomplete, so you can just turn it off as suggested @Nelson, or you can add `.change` event to the input. probably the last one would be better if you want to keep autocomplete on :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `autocomplete="off"` in your input field, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="/results.php">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="query" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the change() jQuery event instead of keyup which will fire on any change in the input, rather than just typing:

```
$(".searchContainer input[name=query]").change(function(){
   if($(".searchContainer input[name=query]").val().length > 0){
       $(".searchContainer input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", false);
   }
   else{
       $(".searchContainer input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
   }
```

});

See:  http://api.jquery.com/change/

**EDIT:**
Since the change() event doesn't seem to be doing it for you, you could try an entirely different approach:

```
$(".searchContainer input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    if ( $(".searchContainer input[name=query]").val().length == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: actually I think that would be great to combine both `change` and `keyup` events, because `change` event is being triggered only when the input loses the focus

Comment: I've tried using .change before, for some strange reason it does not detect change

Comment: So, the problem with the auto-complete is that different browsers handle it different ways...it's not something your jQuery might always (or ever) be able to affect.